# How do I search in HTML generated by Restclient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I search for a word in  the HTML generated by the `Restclient::Response` module?

```
$getresponse = RestClient.get (url)
html=$getadsresponse.body
puts html
```

I can see the HTML that gets generated, but how do I search for words within that HTML?

Comment: You should use an HTML parser (Nokogiri, HPricot, etc).  Can you provide an example of what you want to retrieve by search?  That is, do you just want to know if a word exists in the document, or do you want to return the node(s) that contain it?  Also, does it matter if the word is an attribute or label?

Comment: @PinnyM I want to search a word (ex: some word) which will be in this tag always `<p class="bdy" title="some word"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return wMes_1523188('');" onmouseout="cMes_1523188();" onclick="return false;">some word</a></p>` and then make the test pass/fail depending on whether I get the word or not. Also , "some word" appears only twice in the whole html document. just thought of mentioning that. let me know if any further clarification is required. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an HTML parser to correctly interpret the HTML.  Using Nokogiri with xpath, for example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
found = doc.xpath('//p[@title = "some word"]/a[contains(text(), "some word")]')
found.each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! how can I find which methods and props , I can use on "found" object and "node" object. I tried this but its not printing any value for node.text. The initialization is correct because i checked it with this `doc.search('*').each do |n|
    puts n.name` and it prints the values. any pointers? thanks again

Comment: You can use Node methods on doc and node - http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html. found is a NodeSet as the result of an xpath search - http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html. I would recommend starting with a simpler xpath argument and working up from there.